# SOLVED Using Smarty PHP, syntax errors when splitting the code into smaller parts to be called using include()

Tags: php, smarty, web-deployment, smarty3

**Fixed but I'll leave this here explaining the problem for context.**

**I didn't have the correct path for the file but didn't consider that as it didn't return any errors**

I'm using the newest version of Smarty the PHP template tool on PHP 7.4 (https://www.smarty.net/crash_course)

I've got a page that gets some data from the database and displays each variable for the user using curly braces.

This code works perfectly, as expected and I am able to access all the specified variables by placing them inside my smarty.tpl file using `{username}` for example.

The problems happen when I tried to make things neater and began to put things in files that I was then going to access using the include function. This has caused me to get the error

**> Notice: Undefined variable: smarty in /var/www/html/PROJ1/index.php on line 17**

**> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function display() on null in /var/www/html/PROJ1/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/PROJ1/index.php on line 16**

I'm totally stumped about what's causing this, it's not something I've encountered before. It works when it's a single page, so why wouldn't it work when it's split up into something smaller? I'm not the most experienced PHP coder around, but I've tried adding public into the code, in the hope that the error was caused by the variables not being accessible, but I didn't have any luck with that.

My structure is

core->database->connect.php

core->database->variables.php

includes->include_database.php // includes the connect.php and variables.php pages only

tpl->smarty.tpl // just holds the variables such as {username}

**This is the working index.php page for reference**

```
        <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "jake", "lr");
    
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    
    $query = "SELECT user_id, username, password, first_name, last_name, email, email_code, active, password_recover, type, allow_email, profile FROM users ORDER by user_id LIMIT 3";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    
    /* associative and numeric array */
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
    //printf ("%s (%s) (%s) (%s) (%s) (%s) (%s) (%s) (%s) (%s) (%s) (%s) \n", $row["user_id"], $row["username"], $row["password"], $row["first_name"], $row["last_name"], $row["email"], $row["email_code"], $row["active"], $row["password_recover"], $row["type"], $row["allow_email"], $row["profile"]);
    
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    
    /* close connection */
    mysqli_close($link);
    
    
    include('vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
    
    // create object
    $smarty = new Smarty;
    
    //  variables from database
    $smarty->assign('user_id', $row["user_id"]);
    $smarty->assign('username', $row["username"]);
    $smarty->assign('password', $row["password"]);
    $smarty->assign('first_name', $row["first_name"]);
    $smarty->assign('last_name', $row["last_name"]);
    $smarty->assign('email', $row["email"]);
    $smarty->assign('email_code', $row["email_code"]);
    $smarty->assign('active', $row["active"]);
    $smarty->assign('password_recover', $row["password_recover"]);
    $smarty->assign('type', $row["type"]);
    $smarty->assign('allow_email', $row["allow_email"]);
    $smarty->assign('profile', $row["profile"]);
    
    // display it
    $smarty->display('tpl/smarty.tpl');
    
?>
```

connect.php holds all the database connection stuff

Variables.php

```
    include('vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php'); // smarty php stuff being 
  imported

// create object
$smarty = new Smarty;

//  variables from database
 $smarty->assign('user_id', $row["user_id"]);
 $smarty->assign('username', $row["username"]);
 $smarty->assign('password', $row["password"]);
 $smarty->assign('first_name', $row["first_name"]);
 $smarty->assign('last_name', $row["last_name"]);
 $smarty->assign('email', $row["email"]);
 $smarty->assign('email_code', $row["email_code"]);
 $smarty->assign('active', $row["active"]);
 $smarty->assign('password_recover', $row["password_recover"]);
 $smarty->assign('type', $row["type"]);
 $smarty->assign('allow_email', $row["allow_email"]);
 $smarty->assign('profile', $row["profile"]);?>
```

- And then, finally, I have index.php which is where the errors happen
- 

```
<?php
    include('includes/structure/head.php');
    include('/includes/include_database.php');
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
     ?>
    
    
    
    <body>
    
        <?php
    
        // display it
        $smarty->display('tpl/smarty.tpl');
    
    
        ?>
    
    </body>
```